# Jquery Remote Validate

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I’ve been trying to figure this out for the past week now.  Know there are other questions on here that have been answered that are similar to that but just cannot get it working.

Here’s my jQuery for the remote validation:

```
sponsorcode: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "../process/conn.php",
                type: "POST",
                async:false,
                data: {
                    sponsorcode: function(){
                        return $("#sponsorship").val();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

And here’s the database check (conn.php) (it also marks the ‘used’ column as 1 as each code can only be used once:

```
// Make sure a sponsor code was provided
if (isset($_POST['sponsorcode']) && !empty($_POST['sponsorcode'])) {

    // Escape the sponsor code to prevent SQL injection
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sponsorcode']);

    // Mark sponsor code as used if possible 
    $sql = 'UPDATE teachercodes SET used=1 WHERE sponsorcode="' . $code . '"';
    mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($link)) {
            // Sponsor code hasn't been used before and is valid
            echo (json_encode(true));
        } else {
            //show that the query was successful but that the client was not found
            echo (json_encode(false));
        }
    //free the MySQL result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
    //the form was either not submitted or submitted with an empty value.
    echo (json_encode(false));
 }
```

Comment: What is the actual question? :)

Comment: @Patrick The PHP is returning the wrong result (FALSE, even with codes that are supposed to be TRUE).  It used to return the correct result, but when I added the echo (json_encode), it is now not working.  From what I’ve read, the json_encode is what makes it work with the remote validate?

Comment: I'm assuming you debugged your way through the code and checked that you're in the correct branch of the code, you can check that easily by assigning $_POST['var'] (any var) anything you want, so you can fake a POST request without much hassle, this assumes that the client script sends the request correctly. If the script is indeed landing in the correct branch, echos true but the client thinks it's false, you'll need to check the client side script, maybe it's interperting the code wrong

Comment: @Patrick For some reason, removing the mysqli_free_result($result); line fixed the problem and everything now works fine.  Also had to change the remote code to return $(“#sponsorcode”).val(); <- where #sponsorcode is the id of the specific text box.